# mod_rewrite hide last part of url string

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL: **www.mydomain.com/musician.php?musician=musicianname&id=idnumber**

I am using mod_rewrite to achieve this: **www.mydomain.com/musician/musicianname/idnumber**

This is the rule I am using:

```
RewriteRule musician/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /musician.php?$musician=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

This is working just fine but I want to make this URL more user friendly. I would like to hide "musician" and "idnumber" from the url and have only "musicianname": **www.mydomain.com/musicianname/**

What is the best mod_rewrite rule to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> This is working just fine but I want to make this URL more user
>   friendly. I would like to hide "musician" and "idnumber" from the url
>   and have only "musicianname": www.mydomain.com/musicianname/
>
> What is the best mod_rewrite rule to achieve this?

This doesn't really have anything to do with getting the best rewrite rule. That's not hard at all. In order to achieve what you want, you will first have to re-architect your PHP code. If you remove the idnumber from the query string, I presume it will not have it to look up the record in the database. So you will have to have your code lookup the data by `musicianname` instead.

Once you do that you can simply change your rewrite as such.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /musician.php?musician=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The problem with that is that "musicianname" is not unique so I cannot use it for the query otherwise I would already have done it. I didn't build the app but I am implementing new functionality and improving it, that is why I need nicer URLs. Originally, the URL was www.mydomain.com/musician.php?id=musicianid. I already improved it a bit. The sign up was not designed to take usernames (i use emails), and two users could potentially sign up with the same name. So I cannot use "musicianname" to query the db. I am just trying to fix what has been done before me the best and fastest way I can.

Comment: Then really you're going to have to use the idnumber in the URL. So just www.mydomain.com/musicianname/idnumber. Users are used to seeing that type of URL. it's not like it's hard or long. Look at stackoverlfows URL's they all have the idnumber in it. Not a big deal.

Comment: It is a big deal when your users ask to have their URL like facebook's. They are musicians, not programmers, so they don't care about complexities involved in the process of changing the URL. That is why I posted the question.

Comment: Then you will have to change your process. There isn't a way around that. You have to change your code and maybe start requiring a username. Then use the username for the URL. There is no quick mod_rewrite fix. You will have to do some work to make this happen.

Comment: I am working on other more imporant functionalities, Panama Jack. The url will be mydomain.com/musician/musicianId/musicianName for now. When the right time comes I will implement a username field and write a script to create provisional unique usernames for the musicians already signed up and give them the ability to edit it.